# Capitalize first letter of each word pulled from mysql with PHP/jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I've stored Names all lower case into a mysql db but my users want to see them on the website as first letters capitalized. however i'm trying to figure out a way, whether server-side(PHP) or client-side (jQuery), to do this without changing anything in the database? is this possible?

CODE:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user from `users` order by user asc") or die(mysql_error());
            echo '<select name="user" class="user">';
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<option value='".$row['user']."'>".$row['user']."</option>";
            }
            echo '</select>';
```

Comment: "I've stored Names all lower case into a mysql db". Why on earth have you done this? Names like "Ronald McDonald" can never be correctly re-formatted. As a bit of advice, it's generally a good idea to store information as provided (after escaping, etc.) and then treat it on output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there is also

```
ucwords($row['user']);
```

if you want to capitalize all the words.

Answer (score 6):

You can also do it with CSS:

```
#example {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

PHP has the [`ucfirst`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) function.

```
echo "<option value='".$row['user']."'>".ucfirst($row['user'])."</option>";
```

By only changing the value inside the `option`, rather than the `value` attribute, you can ensure that the same value will be sent back to the server.  Note that you could also use [`strtolower`](http://php.net/strtolower) to ensure that the string is all lower case.

Comment: for some reason that is only capitalizing the first letter of the first word. is there an option to capitalize each first letter, ie. Joe Bloggs, rather than at the moment: Joe bloggs

Comment: @benhowdle89 [`ucwords`](http://php.net/ucwords). See middaparka's point above, however.

Answer (score 1):

in PHP you can use the function UCfirst(str); to achieve this.

You could also do this in your SQL query - but not sure this is best way of doing it.

```
SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(firstName, 1, 1)), 
LOWER(SUBSTRING(firstName FROM 2))) AS properFirstName
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it via css like this:

```
div.caps { text-transform: capitalize; }
```

Result is:

This Is Some Text.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with MySQL as well:

```
SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTR(user, 1, 1)), SUBSTR(user, 2)) FROM `users` ORDER BY user ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user from `users` order by user asc") or die(mysql_error());
echo '<select name="user" class="user">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $user = explode(" ", $row['user']);
    echo "<option value='".$row['user']."'>".ucfirst($user[0]).' '.ucfirst($user[1])."</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the mapping between upper and lower case letters is not the same in every country; the most notable example being Turkey, where i <-> İ and ı <-> I; also, names tend to have more complex capitalisation rules (e.g. "MacDonald", "deVries", "von Hohenzollern" are all proper family names)

I'd run the conversion over the database once, and leave the presentation layer alone.