# Capitalize First word in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, ucfirst

As i am using PHP, So problem comes to me that how can i captilized the first Letter In this Code.

```
<?php foreach($aa as $row):?>

<?php echo ''.$row->username.'' ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Have you googled this at least? there's a function called `ucfirst()`

Comment: perhaps using the ucfirst() function? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php and reading the PHP docs

Comment: There are so many questions here already concerning this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536386/how-to-make-first-letter-of-a-word-capital?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625954/capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-pulled-from-mysql-with-php-jquery?rq=1 and ... (look in the list to the right).

Comment: So is it letter or word?

Comment: [ucfirst](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php). Google doesnt work where you live?

Answer (score 6):

Php has a [`ucfirst()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php)  function it Make a string's first character uppercase.

`<?php echo ''.ucfirst($row->username).'' ?>`

Answer (score 1):

[`ucfirst()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) will help you, but note that it will only convert the first to upper case. All others can also be in upper case, so you may want those to be converted to lower case first.

```
<?php echo ucfirst(strtolower($row->username)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

it'd be easier for you to use CSS instead of a PHP function to display this.

use this line of CSS:

```
text-transform: capitalize;
```

Answer (score 0):

Safe UTF-8 method

```
<?php echo asd($row->firstname); ?>

    function asd($string){
     if(mb_strlen($string)){
     return mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($string,0,1)).mb_substr($string,1,mb_strlen($string));
    }else{
     return false;
    }
    }
```

but in **Codeigniter** you can just do:

```
$this->load->helper('string');
echo humanize($row->username);
```

**Third case** (the one i prefer usually) is to use CSS class:

```
.capitalize{
 text-transform:capitalize;
}

<a class="capitalize"><?php echo $row->firstname; ?></a>
```